# Upgrade Helm 3 in Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I am trying to upgrade helam 3 version into Azure Kubernetes Service.
There is no release in the cluster using helm, but still tiller is running.
Kubectl Server version v1.14.8
Kubectl Client version v1.19.3
Could someone help me to upgrade helm version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/) to install HELM 3 (recommended by AKS)

For installing existing apps with HELM in AKS check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-helm).

If you already have helm 2 and are trying to migrate to helm 3 - check [this](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/v2_v3_migration/) to know the steps and changes in commands from version 3